# How to merge duplicate records with same string, having words in different order. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have duplicate records in my column `full_name`, How do I group records like "Paul Smith" and "Smith Paul" into one record. 
 `Group By` works only when the duplicates are "Paul Smith" and "Paul Smith"

Comment: Not possible cause "Paul Smith" and "Smith Paul" are not same/duplicate.

Comment: You cannot easily split strings in MySQL based on a delimiter. People can have names which contain 2-3-4-...-n words. I would suggest you to change your table to include separate columns for first name and last name.

Comment: Hello, I have been handed down the table with thousands of records, the table was being populated from an application and "Paul Smith" and "Smith Paul" are the same person in this case, as is the case with hundreds of records.